# How to turn off prefill of input field in HTML?

Tags: html, autocomplete

I made a login page where autocomplete is enabled. Whenever I load the page, it is prefilled with the last logged-in username and password that I saved on the browser. I want to keep the autocomplete feature turned on but I just don't want the input field to be prefilled with username/password. If I set the attribute, autocomplete = off it totally turns off the autocomplete.
[image]

Comment: You could try randomizing the name of your inputs, and storing them in the session.

Comment: what is the reason why you need this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

just use autocomplete="off" attribute in the tags you dont want to be prefilled.
`<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">`

heres a link to the w3schools page where they talk about the autocomplete attribute.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp

Comment: OP specifically said he didn't want to use it.